# How to implement multithreading with tornado?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, tornado

I am working with python2.7 with futures module installed.

I am trying to implement multithreading in tornado using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Here is the code that I have implemented.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from base_handler import BaseHandler
from tornado import gen
from pyrestful import mediatypes
from pyrestful.rest import get, post, put, delete
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from spark_map import Map
from concurrent import futures
import tornado
class MapService(BaseHandler):

     MapDB = dict()
     executor = futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)

     @tornado.web.asynchronous
     @gen.coroutine
     @post(_path='/map', _type=[str, str])
     def postMap(self, inp, out):
         db = self.settings['db']
         function = lambda (x,y): (x,y[0]*2)
         future = yield db.MapInfo.insert({'input': inp, 'output': out, 'input_function': str(function)})
         response = {"inserted ID": str(future)}
         self.write(response)

         m = Map(inp, out, function, appName=str(future))
         futuree = self.executor.submit(m.operation())  
         self.MapDB[str(future)] = {'map_object': m, 'running_process_future_object': futuree}
         self.finish()

     @tornado.web.asynchronous
     @gen.coroutine
     @delete(_path='/map/{_id}', _types=[str])
     def deleteMap(self, _id):
         db = self.settings['db']
         future = yield db.MapInfo.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(_id)})
         if future is None:
             raise AttributeError('No entry exists in the database with the provided ID')
         chk = yield db.MapInfo.remove(future)
         response = { "Succes": "OK" }
         self.write(response)

         self.MapDB[_id]['map_object'].stop()
         del self.MapDB[_id]
         self.finish()
```

In the above code, I receive two inputs using the post request in inp and out. Then I perform some operation with them. This operation should last until a delete request is received to stop and remove the process.

The problem I am facing is with the multiple requests. It only executes the first request while other requests wait for the first one to complete thus blocking the main IOLoop.

So, I want to run each process in a separate thread. How should I implement it?

Comment: What does m.operation() do?

Comment: m.operation() is a function of custom class Map that I had implemented. It basically performs some computation on some data. This operation should  run till a delete request is received for that particular operation.

Comment: Sounds like you're blocking in m.operation() and you need to rewrite it to be asynchronous. We'd need to see some code for operation() to be certain, however. Or you could just put a "print" before and after the operation() call.

Comment: Basically, I have a continuos stream of data which i am getting using kafka and I am performing some computation on that data in m.operation() and generating output kafka stream. So, I guess it is blocking the main loop. The input topic name of kafka stream is inp and output topic name is out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `m.operation()` is blocking, so you need to run it on a thread. The way you're doing it blocks the main thread while calling `m.operation()`, and spawns a thread *after*:

```
self.executor.submit(m.operation())
```

You want, instead, to pass the function to a thread which will execute it:

```
self.executor.submit(m.operation)
```

No parens.